# Does dirty-chai not error when not using function call form of property access?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, dirty-chai

I've recently installed [`dirty-chai`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-chai), which states:

> The following built-in assertions are modified by this plugin to now use the function-call form:

The idea being, that hopefully, we get a fail in a test trying to run `expect(true).to.be.true` as it doesn't call the final property being accessed as a function.

But writing that test, gives me no such test failure.

I do note that the same doc also says:

> These forms can also be mixed, but **the chain must always be terminated in the function form** or assertions up to that point in the chain will not execute.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

However I have the code running with all of the below, and no test failures:

```js
expect(true).to.be.true;
expect(true).to.be.ture;
expect(true).to.be.true();
```

I have dirty-chai installed like so, with Mocha 9.1.2, Chai 4.1.2, and the latest version of dirty-chai:

```js
const Chai = require('chai');
const dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai');
....
Chai.use(dirtyChai);
```

this is all wrapped up in a javascript file that's passed to mocha via `mocha <other options> -r ./test/chaiPlugins.js`

Is dirty-chai not behaving as expected, or am I expecting it to behave in a way it doesn't?